# Using Tablesorter Pager widget with POST method

Tags: tablesorter

Is it possible to use Tablesorter Pager widget with AJAX POST requests instead of GET requests?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

The pager widget has the same options as the pager addon, just with a `pager_` in front of the widget option. So include a [`pager_ajaxObject` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxobject) with the type option set to "POST":

```js
$("table").tablesorter({
  theme: 'blue',
  widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'pager'],
  widgetOptions: {

    // modify the $.ajax object to allow complete control over your ajax requests
    pager_ajaxObject: {
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST'
    },

    pager_ajaxUrl: 'mysite/data.json?{filterList:filter}&{sortList:column}',
    pager_ajaxProcessing: function(data){
      if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
        return [ data.total, data.rows, data.headers ];
      }
    }

  }

});
```

Here is a [full list of ajax object settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

---

Update:

```js
$("table").tablesorter({
  theme: 'blue',
  widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'pager'],
  widgetOptions: {

    // modify the $.ajax object to allow complete control over your ajax requests
    pager_ajaxObject: {
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data : { /* include static data here */ }
    },

    pager_ajaxUrl: 'mysite/data.php',

    // use this to function to modify the pager_ajaxObject
    // or include a `beforeSend` callback with the pager_ajaxObject
    pager_customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
        var obj = table.config.widgetOptions.pager_ajaxObject;
        obj.sort = table.config.sortList;
        obj.filters = $(table).data('lastSearch');
        return url; // required to return url, but url remains unmodified
    },

    pager_ajaxProcessing: function(data){
      if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
        return [ data.total, data.rows, data.headers ];
      }
    }

  }

});
```

Comment: Is it then possible to set all necessary variables in POST request ("data" property of "pager_ajaxObject")? {filterList:filter}, {sortList:column} etc.? I need to have URL without GET parameters.

Comment: You can modify the `pager_ajaxUrl` to not include the `{filterList}` and/or `{sortList}`; then use the [`pager_customAjaxUrl` callback](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-customajaxurl) not to modify the url, but update the `pager_ajaxObject` with the filter & sort parameters.